# Python CSV output with Headers

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to save information about traffic from an API to a CSV file using python.

I want the data to go underneath the tag names in a csv output. This is looping every 10 minutes as I want to get a graph / historic data of how bad a specific road stretch is.

It would look like this basically,

```
Traffic Delay - Length In Meters - Departure Time - etc
Data at 0time - Data at 0time - Data at 0time - etc
Data at10time - Data at10time - Data at10time - etc
```

In this example the headings are traffic travel time, length in meters, departure time and traffic delay in seconds.
And the script i'm currently using is below. I've had a go at making a separate dictionary for the header but am in struggle town collating it properly. Any python guru's able to guide this noobie?

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request
import csv
import time

#append to list next
def handleSummary(summary):

   tagsOfInterest=["noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds", "lengthInMeters", "departureTime", "trafficDelayInSeconds"]  # whatever

   #list to use for data analysis
   global data
   global header
   header = tagsOfInterest
   data = []
   #create header dictionary that includes the data to be appended within it. IE, Header = {TrafficDelay[data(0)]...etc
   for child in summary:
       if 'summary' in child.tag:
          for elem in child:
              for item in tagsOfInterest:
                  if item in elem.tag:
                      data.append(elem.text)

#Parse the xml

def parseXML(xmlFile):
    while True:

            with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/-37.79205923474775,145.03010268799338:-37.798883995180496,145.03040309540322:-37.807106781970354,145.02895470253526:-37.80320743019992,145.01021142594075:-37.7999012967757,144.99318476311566:?routeType=shortest&key=notakey&computeTravelTimeFor=all") as fobj:
                xml = fobj.read()
            root = etree.fromstring(xml)
            for child in root:
                if 'route' in child.tag:
                    handleSummary(child)

               # Write CSV file
                    with open('datafile.csv', 'a') as fp:
                        writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=' ')
                # writer.writerow(["your", "header", "foo"])  # write header
                        writer.writerow(data)
                    with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as fp:
                        reader = csv.reader(fp, quotechar='"')
            # next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
                        data_read = [row for row in reader]
                    print(data_read)
            time.sleep(600)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   parseXML("xmlFile")
```

Thanks Stack!

Comment: Show some sample data.

Comment: Have you tried using BeautifulSoup?  From https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/: "Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work."

Comment: I haven't actually. I've almost completed this now though. How would you approach it with beautiful soup?

Comment: Since your post I read about comparisons of lxml and BeautifulSoup.  It seems you are probably okay with your choice of lxml.  To help you I still need to see some sample data.